# Resolve multiple sonar issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-4.5

How can we fix all the issues related to a particular file at a time?

Like in this picture a single file angular.min.js has been marked 3000 issues. This is the angular js library provided by the API. So as we cant fix these issues i need to resolve all these issues in a single attempt.

[image]

Also is there any work around for this sonar issue

**For performance reasons, only the 3000 first lines will be displayed**

When i click the **Bulk Change**
I get the below error. May be because of the  I dont see issues in sonar.log
There is also an warning

*For usability reasons, only the 100 first issues will be fully displayed. Remaining issues will simply be underlined.*

[image]

Comment: Don't run sonar on that file-- you certainly shouldn't expect it not to report problems on a minified file.  Sonar is a source code analyzer, and a minified file is not source code.

Comment: Getting this error after adding it to the exception list. org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
**/angular.min.js
^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2090)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
  while adding it as exception...

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude files which are not relevant to the analysis. See the [SonarQube documentation for that](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus), in particular the "sonar.exclusions" property.

Comment: Isnt it possible to suppress all from the Issues page? Or the Sonar Rest API

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you may have a look at the "Bulk Change" link which appears in your screenshot.

Comment: When i click the Bulk Change I get the above error updated in the Question. I think due to the large number of issues which its not able to display.